# How to make a CSS animation take effect only on ONE element no matter which element calls the animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am new to animations in CSS and this is my code

```
@keyframes fadeOut{
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

I want the above code to take effect on #menu only no matter where it is called, For EG: It is called on a button click but only affects the #menu element. Somewhat like and doesn't do anything to the button

```
button:focus{animation-name: fadeOut;
animation-duration: 4s;}

@keyframes fadeOut{
  #menu{0% {opacity: 1;}}
  #menu{100% {opacity: 0;}}
}
```

But the above code is illegal in CSS and hence, I can't use it.
Is there any alternate way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `animation-name: fadeOut;` to your `#menu` in the CSS and then, for example `animation-duration: 5s;` or whatever duration you want.

Comment: Your question isn’t really specific to animations in the first place. With `button:focus{background:red}`, it would still be basically the same question. You need to apply CSS properties to the elements that you want them to affect, simple as that.

Comment: @CBroe, let me make the question a bit more clearer. a animation is fired when a button is clicked, BUT, the animation changes the background of a div and not the button that called it

Comment: Still makes no difference, you could replace “animation is fired” with “element gets red background” in your phrasing there, and it would still be the same.

Comment: You can only use CSS to change the formatting of a _different_ element, when those elements are in a specific relation to each other. You would need a structure where you could create a “path” from the trigger element to the target element in the DOM, using stuff like adjacent sibling combinator etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `JavaScript`:

**Example 1** 
In this example, we add an `event` for each `element`, each `event` calls the `animation function` that styles the `#menu` element.

```js
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let p = document.querySelector('.p');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');



function animateIt(){
  menu.style.animation = 'fade 1s';
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     menu.style.animation = 'unset';
  }, 1000);
}


btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  animateIt();
});


p.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  animateIt();
});

box.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  animateIt();
});
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fafafa;
  width: 200px;
}

@keyframes fade{
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>

<button class="btn">Click</button>
<p class="p">Or Click Here</p>
<div class="box">Or Click Even Here</div>
```

**Example 2** 
In this example, we simply add the `elements` that will have `events` that `animates` the `#menu` in an `array of objects` with the `class name` and `the event listener` for each one. Each `element` and it's `event` will basically call the `animateIt() function` that *styles and animates* the `#menu`. 

All you have to do is to add a line for each `element` that will call the `animation`, including ONLY the `class name`, and the `event` that calls it.

```js
// Get the #menu 
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');

// Gather the elements in an array of objects including the class name and the event
let elements = [
  {class: ".btn", evt: "click"},
  {class: ".p", evt: "click"},
  {class: ".box", evt: "mouseover"}
];


for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){ 
  // Get the element
  let theTarget = document.querySelector(elements[i].class);
  // Get the event
  let targetEvt = elements[i].evt;
  
  // Add event for each element to call the animation function
  theTarget.addEventListener(targetEvt, (e) => {
    animateIt();
  });
}


// The animation function that styles (animate) the #menu 
function animateIt(){
  menu.style.animation = 'fade 1s';
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     menu.style.animation = 'unset';
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fafafa;
  width: 200px;
}

@keyframes fade{
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>

<button class="btn">Click Here</button>
<p class="p">Or Click Here</p>
<div class="box">Or Hover Here</div>
```

Comment: THANKS BRO!, this is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

As i understood , you have to add the animation to your element Like :

```
/* The animation code */

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

In your case it will be :

```
 #menu {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

You can change 4s to the duration you want.

Comment: Not exactly, You have implemented the animation, appreciated. I've updated the question please take a look at it again